# Is otool available in a stock OS X installation with no Xcode?

Tags: macos

Is `/usr/bin/otool` available in a stock OS X installation where Xcode hasn’t been installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's part of the CLI Developer Tools package in the XCode download:

```
andy:/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Packages$ pkgutil  --payload-files DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg |grep otool
./usr/bin/otool
./usr/share/man/man1/otool.1
```

Comment: It seems that `/usr/bin/otool` later became part of macOS, because when I invoke `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/otool`, it prints `pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Essentials`, among other information.